# Spring Boot Kotlin Project Not Working In Eclipse

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a spring boot project running in eclipse with the following versions

```
Spring Boot: 2.1.6.RELEASE
Kotlin:1.3.41
```

The code runs fine in IntellIJ - but in eclipse I get these errors

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: @Configuration class 'SwaggerConfig' may not be final. Remove the final modifier to continue.
Offending resource: class path resource [com/kotlin/springboot/kotlindemo/config/SwaggerConfig.class]
```

Here is the SwaggerConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    fun api(): Docket = Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    .select()
    .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.boot")))
    .build()

}
```

I have the following plugins setup in my pom.xml file

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                </args>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Again, all works fine in IntelliJ but not eclipse
Any ideas what can be done to resolve this issue in eclipse?

Thanks
Damien

Comment: did you try to remove the final modifier from SwaggerConfig? :)

Comment: It should not work in IntelliJ either (seeing the error message). Spring always sublcasses all classes annotated with `@Configuration` or classes that use code generation features like `@Cacheable`. As Kotlin by default makes its classes final you have to explicitly make them an `open class`

Comment: @Bitman there is no final modifier on the class. If I add open it works but I want to use the kotlin-maven-plugin

Comment: @roookee - the kotlin-maven-plugin  has a compilerPlugin section which should take of that. That is why it is working in intelliJ

Comment: @roookee - this link describes the functionality of the plugin better - https://dzone.com/articles/open-your-classes-and-methods-in-kotlin

Comment: Look around for an m2e adapter or configure it for the plugin. The best best would be to configure eclipse to use maven to compile the code instead of doing it on his own. I personally don't know why you want to rely on a maven plugin if theres such a simple fix, but thats your choice :)

Comment: it keeps the code tidier - the plugin says it will do a job and it should. Does the job in IntelliJ

Comment: @Damien have you installed the _Kotlin Dev Tools_ in Eclipse?

Comment: I have installed Kotlin Dev Tools

Comment: and checked the compiler plugins in preferences Kotlin/Compiler?

Comment: Yes all that looks good in the preferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to the latest version of the kotlin plugin and this resolved the issues I was facing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the **open** Kotlin modifier before the SwaggerConfig class declaration:

```
open class SwaggerConfig {...}
```